# Problems configuring logstash for email output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to configure logstash to send email alerts and log output in elasticsearch / kibana.

I have the logs successfully syncing via rsyslog, but I get the following error when I run

/opt/logstash-1.4.1/bin/logstash agent -f /opt/logstash-1.4.1/logstash.conf --configtest

Error: Expected one of #, {, ,, ] at line 23, column 12 (byte 387) after filter {
if [program] == "nginx-access" {

grok { 
match => [ "message" , "%{IPORHOST:remote_addr} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} [%{HTTPDATE:time_local}] %{QS:request} %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent}” ]
}
}
}

output {
  stdout { }
elasticsearch {
  embedded => false
  host => "

Here is my logstash config file

```
input {
 syslog {
 type => syslog
 port => 5544
}
}


filter {
if [program] == "nginx-access" {

grok {
match => [ "message" , "%{IPORHOST:remote_addr} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} \[%  {HTTPDATE:time_local}\] %{QS:request} %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent}” ]
}
}
}


output {
  stdout { }
 elasticsearch {
  embedded => false
  host => "localhost"
  cluster => "cluster01"
 }
email {
from => "logstash.alert@nowhere.com"
match =>  [
           "Error 504 Gateway Timeout", "status,504",
           "Error 404 Not Found", "status,404"
          ]
subject => "%{matchName}"
to => "you@example.com"
via => "smtp"
body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{@message}"
htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
  }
}
```

I've checked line 23 which is referenced in the error and it looks fine....I've tried taking out the filter, and everything works...without changing that line.

Please help

***Edit***

I've now changed my config to this

```
input {
 syslog {
 type => syslog
 port => 5544
 }
}

filter {
grok {
type => "syslog"
match => ["syslog_program","nginx-access"]
match => [ "message","%{IPORHOST:remote_addr} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] %{QS:request} %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent}" ]
add_field => [ "nginx_response", "%{NUMBER:response}" ]
}
}

output {
stdout {}
elasticsearch {
embedded => false
host => "localhost"
cluster => "cluster01"
}
email {
match => [ "status", "status,304"]
to => "test@test.com"
from => "test@test.com"
options => [ "smtpIporHost", "",
         "port", "",
         "userName", "",
         "password", "",
         "starttls", "",
         "authenticationType", ""
       ]
via => "smtp" # or pop or sendmail
   subject => "Found %{IP:client} Alert on %{@source_host}"
   body => "Here is the event line %{@message}"
   htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
}
}
```

This seems to work, in as much as I can see that it's now recognising things in logstash, and that there is an email plugin command there, but the match fails.....any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you not have to parse out `[program]` first? I don't think the 'input' field does any sort of filtering at all, so you might need to start with `%SYSLOGBASE` http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/grok

You could try instead perhaps:

```
if [message] =~ /nginx-access/ {
```

Which'll keyword match your `message` field. That'll at least tell you if that *is* what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

The [email](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/email) output doesn't support the match function. Instead what you could do would be to [add_tag](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok#add_tag) to a successful grok match, then put a conditional around your email output to only send certain emails depending on the tag you have defined.